# calculating mean

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have a number of files which each contain reviews of a hotel. For each file I would like to write a script which calculates the mean of all values on lines that start with Overall.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
awk -F\> -e '
BEGINFILE {sum=0; count=0}
/<Overall>/ {count++;sum+=$2;}
ENDFILE {printf("%s: %4.1f\n", gensub(".dat","","g",FILENAME),  sum/count);}
' hotel*.dat
```

will e.g. print `hotel1:  8.7`

It uses `>` as delimiter, which nicely gives us the number after `<Overall` into the variable `$2`. This will only work as long as the `>` in `<Overall>xyz` is the first `>` on the line containing `.

The pattern `/<Overall>/` restricts the summation to lines containing `<Overall>`.

Comment: ++, but note that `-e` is _GNU_ Awk-specific and not needed here (without it, your command is POSIX-compliant);  consider omitting the `BEGIN` block to take advantage of Awk's implicit initialization of variables to `0` in a numeric context.

Comment: @user5931562 changed print statement, so that the filename without extension is also printed and the number is also formatted .

Comment: @LarsFischer Thank you :) does this still work if myscript.sh is outside of the folder with the reviews files?

Comment: @user5931562 I would say it depends :) The best would be: you try it out and changed it so that it works for you. In the Question you have got a `cd "$1" OR exit 1` so the awk is called inside the directory with the files. If you dont do the cd but pass `$1/hotel*.dat` as argument to awk, you will get `$1` in the output of the script. So I would say it will work in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the digits after `<Overall>` you can do:

```
awk -F "<Overall>" 'NF>1{sum+=$2;c+=1} END {print sum/c}' file
```

prints `2.5` with your example.

If you want the average of all the numeric fields:

```
awk -F "<|>" '$3~/^-?[0-9.]+$/{a1[$2]+=$3; a2[$2]+=1;} END{ for (e in a1){ print "AVG "e": "a1[e]/a2[e]}}' file
```

Prints:

```
AVG Overall: 2.5
AVG Cleanliness: 3
AVG Location: 2.5
AVG Overall Rating: 3.5
AVG Rooms: 2.5
AVG Check in / front desk: 3
AVG Business service: 1.5
AVG No. Reader: 0
AVG Service: 0
AVG Value: 2.5
AVG No. Helpful: 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly, the first answer is what I was after.